# Creating formula

Tags: php, algorithm

I have, say, a variable X, a variable Y and a variable Z.

```
If Y = 1 then Z = 0.
```

Now all of these examples below are if Y is strictly higher than 1.

```
* If X = 1 and Y >= 2, then Z = 1

* If X = 2 and Y >= 4, then Z = 2
(If X = 2 and Y < 4 , then Z = 1)

* If X = 3 and Y >= 6, then Z = 3
(If X = 3 and Y < 6 but >= 4, then Z = 2)
(If X = 3 and Y < 4 but >= 2, then Z = 1)

* If X = 4 and Y >= 8, then Z = 4
(If X = 4 and Y < 8 but >= 6, then Z = 3)
(If X = 4 and Y < 6 but >= 4, then Z = 2)
(If X = 4 and Y < 4 but >= 2, then Z = 1)

etc etc  ...
```

I'm trying to create a formula to generate that variable Z depending on the information above.

I've tried doing the following :

```
$Z = $X > $Y ? $Y : floor($X / $Y);
```

At first I thought this was doing what I want, but apparently not. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is not a PHP problem in itself. If you can formulate the "algorithm" mathematically, translation to PHP is easy. Try to find a mathematical formular first.

Comment: seems, that Z is independent of X and equal floor(Y/2)

Comment: @splash58 not really, as `If X = 3 and Y < 4` by your formula the result would be `2` but it should be `1`.

Comment: 3/2 = 1.5 and floor -> 1

Comment: It looks like X is an upper boundary that you can test with `min()`

Comment: @splash58 it doesn't work in case of `If X = 1 and Y = 4`, it doesn't give me the required 1 :) Same `If X = 2 and Y = 6` it won't give me 2 ... etc

Comment: @gumakettell so, result should be less or equal X ?

Comment: @splash58 what do you mean? I wrote in my comment what the result should be accordingly.

Comment: min(X, floor(Y/2)) ?

Comment: @splash58 yes that's the answer I recieved if you'd checked it. So you agree with it?

Comment: You did not explain logic of the calculation, only show some example. With them it works, but i'm not sure about another data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to analyze the conditions and what each variable does.

- `X` apparently provides the upper bound for `Z`, so `Z = min(X, ???)`
- conditions are only provided for `Y >= 2`, with `Z` being fixed as 0, if `Y = 1`
- `floor(Y / 2) = Z` within the above range

So `Y` and `X` must be at least 1 and the range of `Z` is `[0, X]`.

Putting this all together:

```
if Y < 1 or X < 1:
    some error ???
elif Y == 1
    Z = 0
else
    Z = min(X, floor(Y / 2))
```